# How to grey-out 1 item in enum property?

Tags: python, scripting

I learned here how to grey-out an item in a menu with the poll function, but this time I need to grey-out the first item in my enum property, whenever a bool property is False...

Is it even possible?

Thank you guys.

Comment: I'm not sure you can disable an enum, but you can dynamically build the items http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10919/15543