# API: Displaying a dropdown list

Tags: python, scripting

I'm currently developing a blender plugin, and need to be able to show drop down lists where users can choose a material and object from the project, but I can't work out how to do it.

Does anyone have an idea how this is done?

Comment: I'm certain that there were two duplicates of this in the last three month. They seem to be hard to find.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/30849

Comment: more enum related (for just materials): http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/10919/30849

Comment: Just selecting a material? How does it should look like? Can you provide an example? Just a simple *dropdown* or a *selection box* in a panel or popup? Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44886/search-enum-list, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/create-an-interface-which-is-similar-to-the-material-list-box/30446#30446

Comment: Selection yeah, so like Blenders internal material selector if that makes sense

Comment: Yep, the links helped, thanks :)
Is it possible to do something like this for primitives too?